# Volunteer Timesheet

Tags: civihr

I've just installed CiviCRM 4.6 on a HostGator hosted Wordpress site and, I should first point out that the not-for-profit I help and I have been looking for a year for a CRM/BI solution and have come up with nothing.  So, finding CiviCRM is a treat.  Especially considering how small we are.

But, our greatest asset is our volunteers, both court appointed for community service, as well as kindness of one's heart (food pantry, etc.).  I cannot for the life of me figure out where to start with recording a volunteer's time.

Our charity (tituscountycares.org) has about 9 different programs- all of them helping the needy.  Some of the recipients may also volunteer.  And some volunteers (and donors) may work on 4 or 5 different programs.

Where is the best place to start with a time sheet?

I started trying to install CiviCRM on a Godaddy account, figured out the MySQL trigger restriction, then figured out MyPHP Admin on HostGator, so I can figure this out.  If you recommend a professional, please make sure they're free.

Kind Regards- Scott

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to the Civi community!

The place you will want to start with volunteer management (including time tracking) is [CiviVolunteer](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civivolunteer), an CiviCRM extension you install to integrate with Civi (here are [extension installation instructions](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Extensions)).  The extension was created by the folks at [Ginkgo Street Labs](https://civicrm.org/providers/ginkgo-street-labs).

They just released the 2.0 version of the extension last month.  Here are a couple of blog posts about it.  The first has a quick screencast:

- [Preview of CiviVolunteer 2.0](https://civicrm.org/blogs/ginkgofjg/preview-of-civivolunteer-20-volunteer-registration-as-shopping-cart)
- [Announcing CiviVolunteer 2.0 Beta2 Release](https://civicrm.org/blogs/ginkgofjg/announcing-civivolunteer-20-beta2-release)

They also have a couple of videos from earlier in 2015 that will give you more of an overview of how the extension works --

- A webinar from early 2015: [CiviVolunteer Tips Tricks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pmtceOfFJyA)
- A session from CiviCon Denver 2015: [Managing Volunteers in CiviCRM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pR9G0nsd9qg&index=34&list=PLjSU7YfE0E01HW7JPVAI80XDI0sgOSPDs)

Comment: Thank you so much.  Not sure why I didn't get the notification of your response, but I see it now and will give it a try tonight and respond back with how it works.

Comment: Sounds good!  Do know that volunteer management with the extension centers around 'events,' so you may have to expand how you guys work with/think about Events to incorporate the time tracking piece.

Comment: Got it.  I was able to add the CiviVolunteer extension successfully, although I'm still clunking my way through finding the timesheet/hours entry.  I'm not asking for help on that yet.  I don't want to overstay my welcome on the tedious things.

Comment: Glad you got it working.  If you have a specific question on the entry process, feel free to ask a different question here on SE.  If the above answer works for you, please accept it (the checkmark outline below the question up/down marker).