# Civihr and time tracking?

Tags: activities, civivolunteer, civihr

I want to use CiviCRM to track volunteer hours and allocate rewards. My question is, how do I use CiviCRM to automatically report on volunteer hours?

Time tracking is used for these reasons:

- 12+ hours: full time staff member.
- 24+ hours:eligible for going to
  the staff after-party.

I work with a Japanese Art and Culture Society. Fancy name for anime convention. We have a major event once a year and a couple of smaller ones.

It would be nice if whatever system we end up, we can use it to:

- Track contact information for our volunteers across all events.
- Track volunteer hours per event.

We have been getting hitting a snag when it comes to the time keeping.  I was reading up on civihr. I haven't seen anything about time keeping, but it does look to be able to handle volunteer info for departments, managers, admins, staff, etc. That may be one part of the solution.

I hear CiviVolunteer may be the time tracking part of the solution.

For the time tracking: 
Can anyone think of a way where we could either have a staff member self punch in and out when they work a shift, or an easy way where we could maybe use the QR codes or ID numbers on our staff badges where supervisors could ideally use their phone to scan a staff members badge to start or end someone's shift?

I know in the past with some version of a check in an out system, we had issues if for some reason someone happened to miss checking out, though this shouldn't really be an issue if we could use phones instead of having to type in data.

To recap, we are looking to create a system that, ideally, would be able to:

- Store a volunteer's info(Personal Data, Department, Contact Info)
- Track different staffers' hours.
- Make reports that show the total hours of each staff member in each department.
- Have different access levels (Volunteer, Department Head, HR Overlord, etc.).
- Make reports with goals.

To expand on that last point, it seems like if there is a way to track time, it should be very easy for our organization's HR Overlord to be able to log in and, with a couple of clicks, be able to pull up a list of all people who qualify for the staff dinner (in this case, they worked 24+ hours between 2017-04-07 08:00:00 and 2017-04-09 17:00:00).

At this point, I'm guessing I would use:

- CiviHR to track Volunteer information, departments, and access permissions.
- CiviVolunteer to track Volunteer hours and to be able to make quick reports.

Can CiviHR and CiviVolunteer even work together in this way?

Comment: PS: I'm relatively new to posting to SE and open to help on rewording my question to make sense and be clear, while being much less wordy (I assume this was a terribly phrases post.)

Answer (score 2):

[CiviVolunteer](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civivolunteer) might be a better fit for your requirements than CiviHR.  See also [Volunteer Timesheet](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8669/volunteer-timesheet)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Aidan that CiviHR may not be quite right for your use case (yet!).

If you are a little more technical I think you could create a solution using:

Drupal webforms (and CiviCRM webform integration)
CiviCRM
CiviVolunteer module

You could create a public webform which you staff can fill in to record their time. This form can be integrated to CiviCRM to create an activity to record the data against their contact record. On the form you could have a field which is the "duration" of time worked (and the date worked) which would be recorded on the activity.

You could then create a report (use the activity summary report) in CiviCRM which sums up the duration of time worked based on various filters.

Answer (score 0):

We built some jiggery pokery stuff so that a user would click a 'start' which would store the data in an Activity field, then would click an 'end' button which would finish that 'session' and hence record the data to calculate the time spent, and do the rest of the summarising of data via Views. Not in a packageable form, but may give you some ideas to work on, or chase us if you want to fund us packaging it up somehow.

Comment: That sounds very useful. Would you mind sharing in one form or another?

Comment: hmm, i think it would take us 2-3 hours to dig it out and ensure it was shareable. won't happen for a while - unless you can get it up our list with some bribery

Comment: or we could look at it at civicon ? damn, just remembered it ws on a client who has since ditched civi, may be more digging to even see what state it is in.

Comment: I don't think there is any huge rush for this; it is something that I'd like to put together over the next couple of months, just to see if this is a system that would be usable and a better fit than what we have (which I can't imagine it wouldn't be as what we are doing now I think is crap - literally just using google sheets and manual input).

Comment: you'll be a civicon?

Comment: St. Louis? Yes, it will be my first one.