# Volunteer hours self-reporting

Tags: civivolunteer

Curious whether there have been any developments on this topic since https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/18095/5446

Comment: You may need to flesh out your specific requirements. There is nothing stopping Activities being used for vol hour self-reporting

Comment: Thanks Pete. The qualm I have re. using activities for this reporting is that, afaik, it won't integrate with the time tracking/reporting built into CiviVolunteer.

Comment: sorry. not used CV so can't comment. We have built a time-tracker in past for client, so person working in the 'calling team' can click 'start timer', then do a bunch of calls (each of which was also 'timed') and then 'end timer'. so that as well as each call being timed, each 'session' was also timed. this was just using Activities and obviously some custom goodness. not suggesting it for you, just ... oh remembering some good old days :-)

Comment: oh i see i rattled on about it at that link too. not quite sure which part of that old thread your link relates to since i don't see '5446' when mousing over the various answers

Comment: Ah, 5446 is the answer from @jamie-novick-compucorp on Apr. 11, 2017. Rattle on Pete, you usually have something useful to say!

Comment: i don't use CV so not sure what it adds. His recommendation of using webforms and activities is my recommendation. I am shooting blind without spending time looking at CV which I am not about to do. Generally tools like CV or CiviSurvey are just sets of pre-built Activities afaik with a bit of reporting around them, all of which i think can be done directly with activities and views/reports but like i say, i don't tend to use them so am zipping my lips hereon